# checking a class to toggle between background colours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have replicated my issue in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66UCX/

All I want to do is toggle between red and white when the user clicks on the td in a table. I have tried using an if statement to test for the background colour like so :
`if($("#fbodytd_"+uid+"_"+row+"_"+col).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)"){`

and that didn't work so I have tried adding and removing a class called 'active' and testing for that. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66UCX/8/ < check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make any binding on your function `function changecream(uid, row, col)`.

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66UCX/2/):

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function(){
if($(this).hasClass("red")){
    $(this).removeClass("red").addClass("white");
} else {
    $(this).removeClass("white").addClass("red");
}
```

});

Edit:
Of yourse if you are only toggling between background color and a chosen color, you could simplify the "on click":

```
$(this).toggleClass("red");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jquery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and your code look like this in $(document).ready function

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#button').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).after('<span> click is active</span>');
    $('span').fadeOut(1000);
});

$('#toggle').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).text('rebind').removeClass('unbind').addClass('rebind');
    },
    function(){

     $(this).text('unbind').addClass('unbind').removeClass('rebind');
    }
);

if($("#toggle").hasClass("unbind")) {
    $('#button').bind('click');
}
else {
    $('#button').unbind('click');
}

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to simply change the background back and fourth (and maybe something else also). Add class like

```
.active
{
    background-color: Red
}
```

and use a code like so:

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery anyway, the following simplified version should do:

```
$('table.bodymap td').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66UCX/10/) for a working example.